# Program Error (yields wrong answer)

Tags: vb.net-2010

I am making a Blackjack program for my programming class (using numbers only from 1 through 10 and cannot use Global Variables, which reason is beyond me). Whenever, I press butHit (button Hit), it always gets the answer, "Bust : Tie" even when the values for both the computer and your own hand are clearly below 21. This happens no matter what if you press butHit.

lblPlayV checks if the player has pressed butPlay before to get the random values and such.

lblCounter represents how many times butHit has been pressed.

I have no idea what could be wrong.

Here's the Code:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub butClose_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butClose.Click
    End
End Sub

Private Sub butPlay_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butPlay.Click
    Dim rand As New Random

    Dim intM1 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)
    Dim intM2 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)
    Dim intM3 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)
    Dim intM4 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)
    Dim intM5 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)

    Dim intOP1 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)
    Dim intOP2 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)
    Dim intOP3 As Integer = rand.Next(1, 11)

    lblPlayV.Text = 1
    lblCounter.Text = 1
    butPlay.Text = "Replay"

    lblM1.Text = intM1
    lblM2.Text = intM2
    lblM3.Text = intM3
    lblM4.Text = intM4
    lblM5.Text = intM5

    lblOP1.Text = intOP1
    lblOP2.Text = intOP2
    lblOP3.Text = intOP3

    lblM1.Visible = True
    lblM2.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub butHit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butHit.Click
    If lblPlayV.Text = 1 Then
        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        If lblCounter.Text = 1 Then
            lblM3.Visible = True

            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text = 21 Then
                If lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text = 21 Then
                    MsgBox("21 : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("21 : You Win")
                End If

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text > 21 Then
                If lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text > 21 Then
                    MsgBox("Bust : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Bust : You Lose")
                End If

            Else
                lblCounter.Text = lblCounter.Text + 1
            End If

        End If

        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        If lblCounter.Text = 2 Then
            lblM4.Visible = True

            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text = 21 Then
                If lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text = 21 Then
                    MsgBox("21 : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("21 : You Win")
                End If

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text > 21 Then
                If lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text > 21 Then
                    MsgBox("Bust : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Bust : You Lose")
                End If

            Else
                lblCounter.Text = lblCounter.Text + 1
            End If

        End If

        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        If lblCounter.Text = 3 Then
            lblM5.Visible = True

            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text + lblM5.Text = 21 Then
                If lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text = 21 Then
                    MsgBox("21 : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("21 : You Win")
                End If

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text + lblM5.Text > 21 Then
                If lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text > 21 Then
                    MsgBox("Bust : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Bust : You Lose")
                End If

            Else
                If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text + lblM5.Text = lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                    MsgBox("Draw")

                ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text + lblM5.Text > lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                    MsgBox("You Win")

                Else
                    MsgBox("You Lose")
                End If
            End If
            lblCounter.Text = 0
            lblPlayV.Text = 0
        End If

        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ButStand_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButStand.Click
    If lblPlayV.Text = 1 Then
        lblPlayV.Text = 0

        If lblM3.Visible = False Then
            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text = lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text > lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

        If lblCounter.Text = 1 Then
            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text = lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text > lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

        If lblCounter.Text = 2 Then
            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text = lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text > lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

        If lblCounter.Text = 3 Then
            If lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text + lblM5.Text = lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf lblM1.Text + lblM2.Text + lblM3.Text + lblM4.Text + lblM5.Text > lblOP1.Text + lblOP2.Text + lblOP3.Text Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: that's what I have been doing. I can't find a reason why it comes to the same result everytime no matter the situation.

Comment: check that you are adding strings. that will concatenate them instead of sum the values as integers.

Answer (score 0):

There is still allot missing in your code....

Like 1010 said if you get 3 cards " 10 10 1" the way you count the result will be "10101"and not 21.

To solve your problem... "Maybe you solve it already".

Use your ints to count "intM1 + intM2 + intM3"

```
Dim intM1 As Integer
Dim intM2 As Integer
Dim intM3 As Integer
Dim intM4 As Integer
Dim intM5 As Integer

Dim intOP1 As Integer
Dim intOP2 As Integer
Dim intOP3 As Integer
```

Place them outside the playbutton so you can use the value everywhere in the form.
Then inside your playbutton you give them a value.

```
intM1 = rand.Next(1, 11)
intM2 = rand.Next(1, 11)
intM3 = rand.Next(1, 11)
intM4 = rand.Next(1, 11)
intM5 = rand.Next(1, 11)

intOP1 = rand.Next(1, 11)
intOP2 = rand.Next(1, 11)
intOP3 = rand.Next(1, 11)
```

Also in your hit button you need to put "lblCounter.Text = lblCounter.Text + 1" at the bottom of the event.

I changed some of your code already ,so here you have it.

```
Dim rand As New Random

Dim intM1 As Integer
Dim intM2 As Integer
Dim intM3 As Integer
Dim intM4 As Integer
Dim intM5 As Integer

Dim intOP1 As Integer
Dim intOP2 As Integer
Dim intOP3 As Integer
Dim intOP4 As Integer
Dim intOP5 As Integer

Private Sub butPlay_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butPlay.Click
    intM1 = rand.Next(1, 11)
    intM2 = rand.Next(1, 11)
    intM3 = rand.Next(1, 11)
    intM4 = rand.Next(1, 11)
    intM5 = rand.Next(1, 11)

    intOP1 = rand.Next(1, 11)
    intOP2 = rand.Next(1, 11)
    intOP3 = rand.Next(1, 11)


    lblPlayV.Text = 1
    lblCounter.Text = 1
    butPlay.Text = "Replay"

    lblM1.Text = intM1
    lblM2.Text = intM2
    lblM3.Text = intM3


    lblOP1.Text = intOP1
    lblOP2.Text = intOP2
    lblOP3.Text = intOP3


    lblM1.Visible = True
    lblM2.Visible = True
    lblM3.Visible = False
    lblM4.Visible = False
    lblM5.Visible = False

End Sub

Private Sub butHit_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles butHit.Click
    If lblPlayV.Text = 1 Then

        If lblCounter.Text = 1 Then
            lblM3.Visible = True

            If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 = 21 Then
                If intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 = 21 Then
                    MsgBox("21 : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("21 : You Win")
                End If

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 > 21 Then
                If intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 > 21 Then
                    MsgBox("Bust : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Bust : You Lose")
                End If

            Else

            End If

        End If

        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        If lblCounter.Text = 2 Then
            lblM4.Visible = True

            If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 = 21 Then
                If intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 = 21 Then
                    MsgBox("21 : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("21 : You Win")
                End If

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 > 21 Then
                If intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 > 21 Then
                    MsgBox("Bust : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Bust : You Lose")
                End If

            Else

            End If

        End If

        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
        If lblCounter.Text = 3 Then
            lblM5.Visible = True

            If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 + intM5 = 21 Then
                If intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 = 21 Then
                    MsgBox("21 : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("21 : You Win")
                End If

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 + intM5 > 21 Then
                If intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 > 21 Then
                    MsgBox("Bust : Draw")
                Else
                    MsgBox("Bust : You Lose")
                End If

            Else
                If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 + intM5 = intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                    MsgBox("Draw")

                ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 + intM5 > intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                    MsgBox("You Win")

                Else
                    MsgBox("You Lose")
                End If
            End If
            lblCounter.Text = 0
            lblPlayV.Text = 0
        End If

        '<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<'
    End If

    lblCounter.Text = lblCounter.Text + 1
End Sub

Private Sub ButStand_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ButStand.Click
    If lblPlayV.Text = 1 Then
        lblPlayV.Text = 0

        If lblM3.Visible = False Then
            If intM1 + intM2 = intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 > intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

        If lblCounter.Text = 1 Then
            If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 = intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 > intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

        If lblCounter.Text = 2 Then
            If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 = intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 > intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

        If lblCounter.Text = 3 Then
            If intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 + intM5 = intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("Tie")

            ElseIf intM1 + intM2 + intM3 + intM4 + intM5 > intOP1 + intOP2 + intOP3 Then
                MsgBox("You Win")
            Else
                MsgBox("You Lose")
            End If
        End If

    End If
End Sub
```